# q.all for angular2 observables

Tags: angular, combinations, observable, subscribe

is there something like q.all to resolve all http api requests in angular2?

In angular1, I can do something like this:

```
var promises = [api.getA(),api.getB()];
$q.all(promises).then(function(response){
    // response[0]  --> A
    // response[1]  --> B
})
```

In angular2, the http module returns Observable,

```
api.getA().subscribe(A => {A})
api.getB().subscribe(B => {B})
```

But I want to resolve A and B together, then do something.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You will need the `.forkJoin` operator for that

```
Observable.forkJoin([observable1,observable2])
       .subscribe((response) => {
          console.log(response[0], response[1]);
       });
```

You can import the `Observable` with;

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
```

Comment: Do you know also RXJS solution for the other variant of $q.all() call, where you can pass an Object rather than an array? It's more elegant approach because you can later address promises by name and not by index.

Answer (score 1):

Angular < 6:

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
    ...
    return Observable.forkJoin(
        this.http.get('someurl'),
        this.http.get('someotherurl'));
```

Angular >= 6:

```
import {forkJoin} from 'rxjs';
...
return forkJoin(
    this.http.get('someurl'),
    this.http.get('someotherurl'));
```