# How To resolve multiple promise in typescript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, typescript, promise

I have a service, which first loads a config file from server through an $http call then in it's success call back I am reading the file content, which actually contains a list of files to load from the server.

So I make another call to server to load all other files. Is there any way in TypeScript to return a promise which will get called only when all the promises are get resolved. Same like $q.all we had in angular 1.X

Comment: Possible duplicate of [q.all for angular2 observables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37172093/q-all-for-angular2-observables)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 promise .all() with RxJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35247310/angular-2-promise-all-with-rxjs)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Promise.all([
    //task1,
    //task2,
    //task3,
  ]).then((value) => {doSomething()});
```

task can be any Promise call